# Magento: How to get an image by label?

Tags: image, magento, view, grid, label

I have another question for you guys :P

On the product grid view i want to change the image when you hover over it with your mouse.
The image i want to switch it too should have a labelname of 'back'.

I almost have it..:P

When i use this code in media.phtml:

```
<?php $imageByLabel = $_product->getMediaGalleryImages()->getItemByColumnValue('label', 'back');?>
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image', $label->getFile())->resize(235, 350);?>
```

It returns something like this: http://www.mywebsite.com/product/images/image1
When i use this in the source attribute of my image it displays the correct image.

But when i use this code in the catalog/product/list.phtml i get the following error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function getItemByColumnValue() on a non-object in C:\Development\FabriqMagento\app\design\frontend\default\fabriq\template\catalog\product\list.phtml on line 95

PS: line 95 is the following line:

```
<?php $imageByLabel = $_product->getMediaGalleryImages()->getItemByColumnValue('label', 'back');?>
```

Any help is appreciated:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you review your code, `$imageByLabel` is not doing anything so it is not needed.

Try:

```
<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages()->getItemByColumnValue('label','black')->getFile();  ?>
```

from `list.phtml`

Answer (score 1):

For not list.phtml:

```
$_item = $this->getItem();
$_product = $_item->getProduct();
```

@Francis Kim - method - also with resiz

```
$_image = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load( $_product->getId() )->getMediaGalleryImages()->getItemByColumnValue('label','FRONTSHOP');
echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(75);
```

Only issue that i found is that its not working with Exclude value